# Python subprocess decoding special characters

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I'm executing a powershell script (which talks to remote machine) using `subprocess`. The issue is that I'm unable to fetch/decode the correct text as expected.

The special characters are wrongly decoded/encoded somewhere during the opeation while using `subprocess`

When I execute the powershell script directly from console the data is intact (though it is not displayed correctly).

[image]

If I copy the output and paste it in notepad I can see the correct text. So no issues while executing manually.

[image]

Now, when executing this using `subprocess`, the output data is incorrect.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['powershell', 'd:\\files_list.ps1'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True
)
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

[image]

I tried various decoding options (`cp1252`, `cp437`), but I'm not able to get the correct text for both the lines. Using the default `utf-8` throws exception while decoding the byte stream.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 40: invalid start byte
```

My guess is that the stdout byte stream itself is incorrect. Below is the value of `output` bytestring. We can see that the first line already comes with `?` mark.

```
b'H:\\sc\\tamil ????????? - Copy.txt\r\nH:\\sc\\\x85, \x8a, \x8d, \x95, \x97,\x85, \x8a, \x8d, \x95.txt\r\n'
```

Can someone please help on the capturing the correct output ?